# AngularJS Date string vs object error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mongodb, date

I'm trying to retrieve a set of user information (by searching firstname) and it returns firstname and booking date (from mongoDB, mongoose schema uses date: Date). Firstname is type=text and booking date is type=date. It returns date as undefined and error message is **Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2017-11-06T16:00:00.000Z to be a date**. I read other questions/answers that it's because type=date expects an object but the JSON is returning a string.

I'm really new to Angular JS and I've tried the suggested methods but no result. I don't know what is missing. Appreciate any specific pointers based on my code

[image]

HTML

```
<form name="updateBookingsForm" ng-repeat="booking in ctrl.bookings" novalidate>
    <input name="firstname" type="text" ng-model="booking.firstname" class="form-control" required>
    <input name="date" type="date" ng-model="booking.date" class="form-control" required>
</form>
```

Controller

```
self.searchAllBookings = function () {
    paAppAPI.searchAllBookings(self.term).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result); //returns array and date undefined
        self.bookings = result;
        }

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.status == 404) {
            self.message = "No bookings found";
            self.showMessage = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Service

```
self.searchAllBookings = function (term) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.get("/api/booking?keyword=" + term).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result); //returns array but date undefined
        if (result.status == 200) {
            defer.resolve(result.data);
        } 
        else {
            defer.resolve(null);
        }

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        defer.reject(err);
    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

Server

```
app.get("/api/booking?", function (req, res) {

    console.log("Search booking > " + req.query.keyword);
    var keyword = req.query.keyword;

    Booking.find({ 
        "firstname" : new RegExp('^'+keyword+'$', "i")
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.status(200).json(result);

        console.log(result); 
        // { _id: 5a1a4e1238dfaa65e5fa59a2,
        //    firstname: 'Emily',
        //    date: 2017-11-20T16:00:00.000Z,
        //    __v: 0 },

        console.log(result[0].date); //2017-11-06T16:00:00.000Z

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `self.bookings` is an array. If so need to loop it over before converting the string to the date.

And then if the date is undefined assign the current date. Otherwise converts the string to Date.

```
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //returns array but date is undefined
    self.bookings = result;
    for(var i=0; i< self.bookings.length; i++){
       self.bookings[i].date = new Date(self.bookings[i].date) : Date.now())
    }


})
```

Comment: After adding this line I console log self.booking.date, I do get the date but it's not being passed down to service (date is undefined)

Comment: do u want to pass the date to service or view it in the html ?

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked! I made a mistake in my code, your FOR statement is correct!!!

Comment: @miintea just a note you can also return the result of the $http.get call from your service function `searchAllBookings` instead of creating your own defer (the $get function returns an HttpPromise which is mostly like a regular promise you get with creating your own deferred object) creating your own can still be useful for caching things in the service but just in case you hadn't noticed.

Comment: @shaunhusain agreed. since http return a promise no need create a new one (using defer object)